# Introduction of $ln$ in defining derivative of $a^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, exponentiation

I am reading R. Shankar's *Basic Training in Mathematics*. In the first chapter, the author is attempting to give meaning to what $a^x$ means for any (potentially irrational) x.

As the very first step, he presents the following method of determining the derivative of $a^x$ (before either $a^x$ or $ln$ have been defined):

[1] $\Delta a^x$ = $a^{(x + \Delta x)} - a^x$
[2] = $a^x(a^{\Delta x} - 1)$
[3] = $a^x(1 + \ln(a)\Delta x + ... - 1)$

[4] $\frac{da^x}{dx}$ = $a^x\ln(a)$

He justifies step [3] by saying that it is obvious that $a^{\Delta x}$ is very close to 1, and that:

> The deviation from 1 has a term linear in $\Delta x$, with a coefficient that depends on $a$, and we call it the function $\ln(a)$...

How is he justified in asserting that, for any choice of $a$, the deviation from $1$ must be represented by a term linear in $\Delta x$?

I can see that, if there were any higher-order terms $a_2(\Delta x)^2$, $a_3(\Delta x)^3$, ..., they would all disappear as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ in the derivative, but how do we know that a suitable linear function even exists?

Comment: Can you use the fact that $a^{\Delta x} = e^{\Delta x \ln(a)}$ and expand the exponential for $\Delta x$ small?

Comment: This is typical of many books by Indian authors and some non-Indian authors. They are just being intellectually dishonest. There is no place for hand-waving in mathematics. The development of $a^x$ and its properties without the use of logarithm function is slightly difficult and presented in my [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is a little sketchy.

$\frac {d}{dx} a^x = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {a^{x+h} - a^x}{h} = a^x \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {a^{h} - 1}{h}$

And then with a wave of the hand.... we assume that this limit exists.  And lets call it, "$\ln a.$"

However, it has not been yet been demonstrated that this function of $a$ has the properties of a logarithm, or what the base of this logarithm might be.

Comment: The author goes on to discuss the properties of this just-introduced $\ln(a)$,  and introduces $e$ in a similar fashion ("...there is clearly some a > 1 for which $\ln(a)$ = 1. Let us call that number $e$"), but it all seems rather circular to me.

Comment: It is pretty easy to show using the definition provided that $\ln 2 < 1 < \ln 3$ and that $\ln a$ should be a continuous function.  So, by the IVT there exists some number $e$ such that $\ln e = 1$  Even so, $e$ has not been defined with any precision yet, shown that it exists.

Comment: My teacher took it from the other direction.  He defined $\ln a = \int_1^a \frac {1}{x}\ dx$ and then showed that this function had the properties of a logaritm.

Comment: How about this $e = \sum_\limits {n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{n!}, e^2  = 1^2 + \frac 2{1!} + \frac {2}{2!} + (\frac {1}{1!})^2 + \frac {2}{3!} + \frac{2}{1!2!} + \frac {2}{4!} + \frac {2}{1!3!} + (\frac {1}{2!})^2 = 1 + 2 + \frac {4}{2!} + \frac {8}{3!} + \cdots \frac {2^n}{n!} \implies e^x = \sum_\limits {n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!} \implies \frac {d}{dx} e^x = \sum_\limits {n=1}^\infty \frac {nx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_\limits {n=1}^\infty \frac {x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = e^x$